# How do I create recursive object type in typescript for css styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, recursion

I am using `React.CSSProperties` for creating css variables so I can create like

```
let css: React.CSSProperties = {
  position: "relative",
  display: "inline-block",
  background: "red"
}
```

I am trying to create a theme which will have css variables at the root level or nested inside modifiers like size(sm,md,lg) or variant(light,dark) or other as below

```
let theme: MyTheme = {
  background: "red",       // css
  color: "white",          // css  

  button: {                // custom: component name Level1
    background: "red",     // css
    color: "white",        // css

    light: {               // custom: modifier variant Level2
      background: "red",   // css
      color: "white",      // css

      hollow: {            // custom: modifier Level3
        borderColor: "red",
        color: "red",
        background: "transparent",
      }
    }
    dark: {
      background: "red",
      color: "white",

      hollow: {
        borderColor: "black",
        color: "black",
        background: "transparent",

        modfierLevel4: {
          some: "css"

          modfierLevel5: {
            some: "css"

            modfierLevel6: {
              some: "css"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I am looking for recursive object type in typescript like below, but ending up in circular reference?

```
type Modifiers = 'button' | 'dark' | 'light' | 'otherModifiers'

interface Theme extends React.CSSProperties {
 [k in Modifiers]?: Theme;
}
```

---

I am able to find the answer (below) close to it.

```
type Theme = React.CSSProperties & { [keys in Modifiers]?: Theme }
```

But facing some issue. If modifier name is given invalid like "btn" instead of "button"

- error is thrown properly at level 1 (as expected)
- but no error is thrown from level 2 and above. (but expected to throw error)

How should I create types for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using TS3.4 or below:

This is the result of a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13813) in which [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are not performed on nested intersection types like `Theme`.  Technically speaking, types in TypeScript are generally "open" or "extendable", meaning it's okay for a value of a type to have more properties than mentioned in its type definition.  You rely on this with things like `interface A { a: string }` and `interface B extends A { b: string }`, where a value of type `B` is also a value of type `A`.

But usually when people are using object literals like you are, it's a mistake to add extra properties... especially in your case where the "extra" property is just a typographical error for an optional property.  So the compiler decides that when you're assigning a new object literal to a type, extra properties are an error.  That is, types of fresh object literals are "closed" or "[exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)"...

...well, or they should be, except for this bug with nested intersections.  In TypeScript 3.4 or below, this is the behavior:

```
type Foo = { baseProp: string, recursiveProp?: Foo };
const foo: Foo = {
    baseProp: "a",
    recursiveProp: {
        baseProp: "b",
        extraProp: "error as expected" // error 
    }
}

type Bar = { baseProp: string } & { recursiveProp?: Bar };
const bar: Bar = {
    baseProp: "a",
    recursiveProp: {
        baseProp: "b",
        extraProp: "no error?!" // no error in TS3.4 
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20baseProp%3A%20string%2C%20recursiveProp%3F%3A%20Foo%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22a%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20recursiveProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extraProp%20%22error%20as%20expected%22%20%2F%2F%20error%20%F0%9F%91%8D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20%7B%20baseProp%3A%20string%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20recursiveProp%3F%3A%20Bar%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22a%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20recursiveProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extraProp%3A%20%22no%20error%3F!%22%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%20in%20TS3.4%20%F0%9F%98%95%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Luckily for you, this error has been [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30853) for TypeScript 3.5, which should be [released](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30555) on May 30, 2019, or you could try out the nightly build of TypeScript via `typescript@next`

If you can't wait until then or can't upgrade soon, you can work around this by using a mapped type to replace the intersection with a more normal-looking object:

```
type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type Bar = Id<{ baseProp: string } & { recursiveProp?: Bar }>;
const bar: Bar = {
    baseProp: "a",
    recursiveProp: {
        baseProp: "b",
        recursiveProp: {
            baseProp: "c",
            extraProp: "error yay" 
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20Id%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20Id%3C%7B%20baseProp%3A%20string%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20recursiveProp%3F%3A%20Bar%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22a%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20recursiveProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20recursiveProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseProp%3A%20%22c%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extraProp%3A%20%22error%20yay%22%20%F0%9F%91%8D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

The expected error shows up, and all is right with the world.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This works fine if the type "Modifier" is well defined. But instead if create like `type Modifiers = 'dark' | 'light' | string;`, then I am facing error. Is there any way I can create nested type for **any** custom keys?

Comment: `type Modifiers = 'dark' | 'light' | string` is the same as `type Modifiers = string`.  So at that point you're just using an index signature and you need to make sure that the value type conforms to the value types in `React.CSSProperties`.  This seems like a separate question requiring its own code and specific errors, etc, for someone to answer.